# Redirect Subdomain to Main Domain Via .htaccess (Not the Same Structure)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

How to redirect my subdomain to main domain (the structure is not the same)

For example :
(Case 1)

I wanna redirect: https://sub. mywebsite.com/shop/iphone7
to: https:// mywebsite.com/product/iphone7

(Case 2)

I wanna redirect: https://sub. mywebsite.com/collections/iphone-7-accessories
to: https:// mywebiste.com/cat/gadgets/mobile-accessories/iphone-7-plus-cases-accessories/

Regards,

Regards,